# How to run a Jenkins build based Python code from GitHub?

Tags: python, jenkins, github

I have simple Python code inside a GitHub repo:

```
print "hello world"
```

How to create a Jenkins build to run this Python code directly from a GitHub?

Comment: Maybe you should stick to one question at a time? You seem to be in the early stages of figuring out Jenkins, which makes it likely you'll ask questions that don't make much sense. Again, why do you just want to print stuff in your build? Also: upgrade to Python 3.x.

Comment: Want to print stuff in order to learn what is happening and later build more complicated builds. Python 2 is used by a team so can not just decide myself to change to 3.

Comment: Note that you've already had this question closed once: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48832916/3001761. Please don't ask duplicates.

Comment: Was it answered?